# Connecting to a remote Azure Redis Cache using Redis CLI

Tags: .net, windows, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to use `redis-cli` to connect to my Redis cache hosted in MS Azure.

I created a shortcut to the executable in Windows, passing through the hostname port and pw:

`"C:\Program Files\Redis\redis-cli.exe" -h myredis.redis.cache.windows.net -p 6380 -a "myaccesskey"`

But it just hangs there.

P.S the connecting string *is* valid, because it's the same one i'm using in my client library to successfully connect.

What am i doing wrong?

I need a way to remotely (e.g from my PC running windows) perform admin-style operations against my remote Redis cache, such as removing given keys, or flushing a database.

The only other thing i can think of is to write a console application that uses a library such as [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) to do the work i need, ad-hoc.

Any advice on what i should be doing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to turn on the non SSL port. Read this for more information http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-faq/#how-can-i-run-redis-commands